# Get List of items from DataGridView based on a List of row indices

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` similar to the one below:

```
ID    Name    Data1   Data2
1     MM      X       1000
2     ST      Y       1000
3     EC      Z       1000
4     JT      T       1000
```

I also have a list of row indices that are important to me.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(2);
```

Now what I want to do is grab the values from the Data1 column in my `DataGridView` that corresponds to those row indices.  So what I am looking to get out (in this example) is some datatype which contains "Y" and "Z".

I don't want to iterate over the `DataGridView` because I have a large sample of data there.  Is there a way to do this with LINQ?  I'm still a LINQ beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> columnValues = myList.Select(x => data.Rows[x].Cells["Data1"].Value);
```

This code assumes that a reference to your `DataGridView` is stored in the variable `data`.

Comment: This is perfect.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Only trouble was I had to change from a List to IEnumerable type.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cam use

```
int id= (int)myList[0];

string[] Data1= (from DataRow row1 in Datatable.Rows
                          where row1["ID"] == id
                          select row1["Data1"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Now You can access the data1 by using the string array corresponding to the list values